# Proof of existence of infinitely many primes that divide the sequence $\{S(k)\}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^k$ where $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ forms an AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, arithmetic-progressions

**For the sake of a mathjax solution and because of finding an error in my previous solution (which I had posted here for correction), I have edited the whole document**

> Let $a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ be a non constant Arithmetic Progression.
>
> Define: $$S(k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^k$$
>
> Prove that there are infinitely many primes which divide the sequence  $\{ S(k) \} _{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ where $S(k)$ doesn't remain constant.

---

> The term: *infinitely many primes which divide the sequence  $\{ S(k) \} _{k\in \mathbb{N}}$* is a bit messy to understand.
>
> **Clarification of the statement:**
>
> The sequence $\{S(k)\}$ has infinitely many terms different terms since it's not constant. Now the terms are not restricted to being divisible by only a certain number of primes. Like suppose, consider a set of primes: $\mathcal{P}=\{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_m\}$. Then there will exist a term in the sequence of $\{S(k)\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which will get divided by a prime $p_j$ such that $p_j \notin \mathcal{P}$.

---

**Doubt:**

Here (below in the form of images) I have provided half of the solution, as best I could.
I think I'm not wrong.

May I get some guidance to complete the second case?

**Solution:**

First, let us assume to the contrary and let $\mathcal{P}=\{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_m\}$ denote the set of primes that **ONLY** divide $S(k)$ and suppose $\text{GCD}(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)=d$. 
Then we get $a_i=db_i$ such that $\text{GCD}(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n)=1$
Choose $p > n$ which means $p \nmid n$.

Fix a prime $p \in \mathcal{P}$ and show that there exists a prime $p \mid S(k)$ such that $p \notin \mathcal{P}$ leading to a condration and hence proving the inexistence of finitely many primes that divide the sequence.

We get two cases:

**Case 1: $p \nmid d$**

If $p \mid S(k)$, then, $p \mid  d^k \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$ and since $p \nmid d$, we see $p \mid \sum b_i$. 
Set $k=\prod (p_i-1); ~ p \in \mathcal{P}$
From Euler's theorem (the one that uses Totient\Phi function), we get that $b_i \equiv \{0,1\} \pmod p \implies \sum b_i \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ and hence we get the desired contradiction.

**Case 2: $ p \mid d$**

(Could not solve)

Comment: Bumping the topic, can anyone check my proof? Is there any loophole?

Comment: No, simply no. Your main idea looks somewhat promising, but your work is really hard to read. If you want someone here to check it, turn it into a nice to read form... Two short comments from the first page: The question talks about an arithmetic progression $a_i$ and you use some $b_i$ that don't have a common divisor; why?

Comment: I have initially shown that irrespective of the sequence being in AP, just if all terms are distinct and have GCD=1, then we'll get infinitely many primes dividing the sequence. And then, I have have considered the AP (having GCD=d). It's like a lemma that I have used initially

Comment: Take $n=1$ and you only get finitely many primes. Take $n = 2$ and $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 1$ and you will get no primes at all. I'm sure there are other counter examples. Thus, the first step should be to state the question correctly. Then you might want to ask a single question regarding your proof, not just give three pages and say "please read"...

Comment: @DirkLiebhold The AP and value of $S(k)$ is non-constant. And in your first case, the AP becomes constant. Hence it won't work. And in the second case, $S(k)=1$ which makes it constant.

Comment: For a prime $p$ and a sequence $\{S_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ what is the meaning of "$p$ divides the sequence $\{S_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$"? I would understand it as $\forall k\in\Bbb N\colon p\mid S_k$, but that won't make sense here ...

Comment: I understand that the question​ is a bit messy and even I had problems understanding it initially. The sequence $\{S(k)\}$ has infinitely many terms. Now the terms are not restricted to being divisible by only a certain number of primes. Like suppose, consider a set of primes: $\mathcal{P}=\{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_m\}$. Then there will exist a term in the sequence of $\{S(k)\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which will get divided by a prime $p_j$ such that $p_j \notin \mathcal{P}$. This is the best I can make my question clear.

Comment: Is the question clear now?

Comment: The proof is poorly written in the sense that it is not at all clear how anything you're saying leads to a proof. Explain what you are proving, and how this helps to prove the final result. Also your notation is often convoluted; in stead of writing $b_1^k\equiv1\pmod{\mathcal{P}}$, write $b_1^k\equiv1\pmod{p}$ for all $p\in\mathcal{P}$. This is just one example, there are many. It kept me from finishing even the first page.

Comment: I'm bumping the topic since it's edited a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that the prime divisors of $S(k)$ belong to $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_m\}$ for any $k\geq 0$. [By Van Der Waerden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem), there are arithmetic progressions $k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots,k_\eta$ of arbitrary length such that $S(k_1),S(k_2),\ldots,S(k_\eta)$ are multiples of some $p_\mu$, and we may assume without loss of generality $k_\eta>p_\mu$. [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) then imply that $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are multiples of $p_\eta$. We may define $\tilde{a}_j = a_j/p_\eta$ and repeat the same argument, but since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD an infinite descent is not allowed and the claim is proved.

Comment: (+1) for the solution. Can my solution be checked?

Comment: @Mathbg: of course, just give me some time. Can you convert your work into MathJax?

Comment: Sure sir, I can give you enough time for checking it. But since I'm not a pro at typing, it would take me enough time to type out the whole thing. I am sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Mathbg: at first sight, your solution looks correct. The idea of considering specific exponents of the form $A(p_1-1)\cdots(p_m-1)$ and exploit Fermat's little theorem is slick. It is a pity a less constructive approach like mine leads to a much shorter solution :D

Comment: True indeed. Yes, that was my idea to construct and exploit using Euler's theorem (stronger than FLT) but I'm afraid my proof maybe hard to read.

Comment: @Mathbg: well, the main idea is clear and efficient. Details can be boring to outline, but they are secondary.

Comment: The idea is clear but I'm bothered if there is any fallacy/loophole/trivial errors in the proof since these won't be considered strong/rigorous in Olympiads. Sir, you may take your time to get it checked. I would be grateful to you!

Comment: Sir, I have converted my work into MathJAX. Can you help me now?

Comment: @Mathbg: in your case $2$, just replace $a_i$ with $a_i/p$ and restart, like I do at the end of my proof.

Comment: Sir, I have done that myself. But I didn't know how to inform that here. I am trying to close down the topic now. Thanks for your constant help, though